# How to remove click ads from fresh WordPress site?

Tags: virus

I bought a hosting and domain from Godaddy, Installed WordPress. Now the site is showing ads on every page after clicking anywhere on the pages or in the admin section as well. I have tried manual WordPress install also, changed the cPanel password, FTP password. Removed all files before fresh install. It starts showing ads immediately after install. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress doesn't include ads of any kind, so there's no standard process for removing them.

Possible reasons you could be seeing ads are:

- Your host is adding them, possibly as a condition of a cheap/free hosting plan.
- You installed a pirated theme or plugin that contains malicious code.
- Your website has been hacked in some other way. This seems unlikely if you saw them right after installing.
- *You* have been hacked, and you have malware on your computer that's displaying ads on web pages.
- Your ISP is injecting them.

This site is not an appropriate place for resolving any of those issues, so my suggestion would be to start by speaking to your host.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I have verified and found that my ISP is the reason for this issue. Can you please suggest what i can do to resolve this as they are not getting accepting it is their fault.